# Creating questions for for infinite subset and finite subset

Tags: real-analysis

(1) An open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, other than $\mathbb{R}$ itself, such that  $\mathbb{Q} \subset U$.

(2) An infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for which $S' = \emptyset$, that is, $S$ has no limit points.

** DO NOT NEED ANSWERS FOR THEM.** I want your help to twist the questions a little bit with the goal to get another set of questions with more difficulty or similar difficulty and requires different tricks to solve the questions. Please provide the answers and explanation too

Answer (score 1):

For 1), since you can enumerate the rational numbers, you can create an open ball $B_n$ around each $q_n\in\mathbb Q$ such that $|B_n|\to 0$ sufficiently quickly as $n\to\infty$.

For 2), you need a sparse infinite set in $\mathbb R$. Try separating every point in $S$ by some fixed $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: 1)What is the smallest closed subset $C$ containing $\mathbb Q$? 2)Is this closed set the closure of $S$ --the smallest open set containing $\mathbb Q$? 3)What is the cardinality of the collection of subsets of $\mathbb R$ without a limit point? 4)Are there uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ without a limit point (no)? Prove or disprove.

Comment: could you provide your answers in a gray text so that I can only view them when I click on it?

Comment: Gladly, but I don't know how to do that. Any chance you know?

Comment: Do you mind giving your answers in a new post so that when I look at your questions and I won't distract by your answers

Comment: Sure, let me do it just below.

Comment: I just posted it. Does that work?

Comment: I mean the answers as well

Comment: O.K, give me some time then, and I'll get to it, tho I have to go out and dinner for a while. I'll be back with it, tho.